# Multiple select values and GET-string

Tags: php, list, get

I have a form that has a select input. Its method is GET.

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
<select name="select[]" multiple>
  <option value="0">Option1</option>
  <option value="1">Option2</option>
  <option value="2">Option3</option>
  <option value="3">Option4</option>
  <option value="4">Option5</option>
</select>
</form>
```

If I would select option 2 and 4 the url will look like: mydomain.com/index.php?select[]=2&select[]=4

I want it to look like (preferable without the square brackets)

mydomain.com/index.php?select=2+4

I suspect I need a client-side solution for this, but I don't know any javascript. Or first load a page that alters the values and then redirects to a new page with header(location:'')?

Comment: how the url 'looks' should not matter one jot

Comment: That's not how that works. `?select=2+4` would imply a single input with the value of "2 4". What's wrong with letting form submission work as it was designed to work? This is an extremely well solved problem, and you're trying to mess with it.

Comment: You are both right that it should be left like it is. Yet even for the simply fact of curiosity I wish to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your intent is to sum the values and return (6) rather than (4+2). The following snippet does both, use the one you want and scrap the other.

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <select multiple id="selector">
        <option value="0">Option1</option>
        <option value="1">Option2</option>
        <option value="2">Option3</option>
        <option value="3">Option4</option>
        <option value="4">Option5</option>
    </select>
    <input type=hidden name=select1 value=0 id=hiddenSelect1>
    <input type=hidden name=select2 value=0 id=hiddenSelect2>
    <input type=button onclick=showw();>
    <input type=submit onclick="return sumValues();">
</form>


<script>
    function sumValues()
    {
        var values = $('#selector').val();
        if (values === null)
        {
            $('#hiddenSelect1').val("");
            $('#hiddenSelect2').val(0);
        }
        else
        {
            var valstring = values.join("+");
    //string (1+2+...)
            $('#hiddenSelect1').val(valstring);
//actually sum them
            var sum = 0;
            values = valstring.split("+");
            for (var i = 0, len = values.length; i < len; i++)
            {
                sum += parseFloat(values[i]);
            }
            $('#hiddenSelect2').val(sum);
        }
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I don't want to sum them to 6, but show as  4+2, so last part of the code is not applicable. However some notes on the code you gave: 1) There are other input types in the same form, so calling sumValues would skip the other inputted fields. 2)I need an action=example.php because it needs to load the new page

Comment: this stuff should just be a starting point. sounds like you know what you want to do with it, try and modify the JS presented here to fit it into what you want. The value in "hiddenSelect1" actually is what you want, if you select 4 and 2 it will literally be "4+2", so erase the summing code if you dont need it, change the action to the correct .php, etc.